# Trouble understanding and using Statsmodels' SARIMAX `conf_int()` output

Tags: python, forecasting, statsmodels

I've been trying to use statsmodels' SARIMAX model but return a confidence interval around my predictions.

**My goal is to generate series of predictions for the upper and lower bounds of the confidence interval.**

I attempted to fit my model, then use `get_prediction()`, and finally `conf_int()`. `get_prediction()` returns data for each of my index as I expected. However, `conf_int()` returns a strange matrix:

```
        0   1
ar.S.L7 0.018806    0.194818
ma.S.L7 -0.830238   -0.717128
sigma2  40.832875   48.105937
```

that I don't understand. I noticed that these are the parameters for a model, but I don't know how to use these to get upper and lower predictions for each of my indices.

I've consulted: [this](http://www.chadfulton.com/posts/state_space_python.html), [this](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_local_linear_trend.html), and [this](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html), but none of them seem to have the same problem. I've also looked over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700424/python-statsmodels-using-sarimax-with-exogenous-regressors-to-get-predicted-mea). I have attempted to follow their code as closely as possible, but can't recreate the problem.

Comment: `conf_int` means different things depending on which statistic is refers to. `conf_int` of a model results instance are the confidence intervals for the estimated parameters. `conf_int` in a prediction or forecast are either prediction intervals for a new observation or confidence interval for the expected value of a new observation.

Answer (score 2):

When you do :

```
model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(params)
fit_model = model.fit()

nforecast = 144
forecast = fit_model.get_prediction(end=model.nobs+nforecast)

ci = forecast.conf_int()

print(ci.head())
```

You should get:

```
          upper [name of your feature]     lower [name of your feature]

 time1           0.018806                    0.194818 
 time2          -0.830238                   -0.717128
 time3           40.832875                   48.105937
```

the default headings of ci is just 'upper' and 'lower' if you don't have features headings in your original data.